# Creating UIButton in Xcode with icon on right side and text on left side

Tags: swift, xcode, button, uibutton, label

I'm trying to create an `UIButton` in Swift where the label is 20px from left and the icon (SF Symbol) is 20px from the right side, please see the picture attached.

[image: Picture was taken from Apple COVID-19 app]

Comment: So are you using UIKit or SwiftUI?

Comment: I am using UIKit sorry for confusion

Answer (score 1):

I created this custom class for you (when declaring a button, write Covid19Button instead of UIButton in order to  use it).

```swift
class Covid19Button: UIButton {
   //declare here the objects or variables you want in your custom object
    var label: UILabel!
    var image: UIImageView!
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
       commonInit()
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
     commonInit()
    }
    
    func commonInit(){
//Set your objects' frame and other stuff like colors ecc note that here I set random dimensions. The x should be ok however. You can change them as you prefer 
        label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: 100, height: frame.height-40))
        image = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: frame.width-20-image.frame.width, y: 20, width: 50, height: frame.height-40))
        
        addSubview(label)
        addSubview(image)
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: I put the code in my .swift file and put a class name to button "Covid19Button" but it didn't work

Comment: What do you mean? It wasn't as you expected or what?

Comment: Well when I ran the app the button stayed normal without any formatting

Comment: Are you on storyboard or do you do it programmatically? If you're on storyboards set the class both on storyboard (select the button and go on identity inspector, then where you  read class write `Covid19Button `) and in code like this `@IBOutlet weak var btn: Covid19Button!`.